# JQuery, How can I make only the main <div> be clickable?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am creating a JQuery plugin to toggle between a certain div. I have one div that is visible that you can click on to toggle the hidden div. I get the hidden div to appear but when I click on the hidden div it disappears. How can I make the hidden div appear and stay visible even when I click on the hidden div?

Here is my code.

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='stylesheet.css'/>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script>
</head>
<body>  

<div id="clickable_box" class="tooltip4"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">  
$('div.tooltip4').tooltip()
</script>       

</body>  
</html>
```

CSS:

```
#appearing_box {  
display: none; 
border: 1px solid #BFBFBF;
height: 50px;
width: 150px;
}  

#clickable_box {
height: 50px;
width: 50px;
border: 1px solid black;
}
```

JQuery:

```
(function($){  
$.fn.tooltip = function(options) {  

    this.each(function() {  
        var $this = $(this); 
        var $box = $('<div id="appearing_box"> <form><textarea>When?</textarea><form> </div>');     

            $this.click(function() {  
                $($box)
                .appendTo($this)  
                .css({
                backgroundColor: '#0099ff' 
                }),   
                    $box.toggle();   
            });     
    });    
};  
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: As a note: Using this more than once will result in invalid HTML as you're going to attach more than one element with the same id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since your appering_box div is inside `.tooltip` .. the click on `appering_box` is calling the `.tooltip` click .. so  try `e.pstopPropagation()` on appearing_box click function to stop the event bubble..

try this

```
$.fn.tooltip = function(options) { 
  ...  
 //your codes
};
$(".tooltip4").on('click', "#appearing_box",function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
})
```

[working fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/gUjNy/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Attach the following delegated event handle to your code:

```
$this.on('click', '#appearing_box', function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Here is [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gUjNy/).

Comment: i think since your code is inside the each function... multiple on click event will be there.. which is not required if you delegate it to tooltip4 outside the function....:)